# How can I access the admin object's data in a Sonata Admin form

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

I want to access the object being edited within a sonata admin edit form. Something like:

```
{% for prop, value in admin.getDatagrid(object.id) %}
<li>value</li>
{% endfor %}
```

How can I access the object's data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to do this:

```
{% for item in object.items()%}
<li>{{item.id}}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

'object' accesses the entity directly and I have a getItems method on the entity